# RDS external Manifest with multiple monitors

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remoteapp, mstsc

One of our remote-workers has a Surfacebook (Win10 64-Bit) with a 3000x2000 resolution with which he connets to our RDS-Serverfarm (Win Serv 2012 R2) by RemoteApplication. No VPN or anything else, just RDS.

We had performance Issues on his machine because it's a high-DPI screen and couldn't handle the lower resolution of the server. I solved this problem by using an external manifest for mstsc.exe which I found [here](https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2016/03/19/fix-remote-desktop-dpi-scaling-issues/).

Now the RemoteApplication is really fast and very good to work with, just as it should be. BUT the surfacebook user has 2 external monitors connected to his machine and now, with that external manifest, the RemoteApp(mstsc) can only handle one screen. So when you want to drag an application to another screen, it will not show up. it will only show on his main screen.

I guess this error occurs, because the manifest tells mstsc to use the servers "monitor property" (i don't know a better word how to call this) and since the server only has one monitor, the mstsc of the client also can handle only one monitor.

my question would be: how can I solve this in one of the either ways:

- make mstsc accept more than one screen by editing the manifest
- make the server think it has up to three monitors

What would you do in this situation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the rdp client overlay into the two/screen screen on the client computer ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 sorry, i forgot to reply. I guess the best solution would just be to make the server think it has multiple monitors (3 for example). the server has no monitor connected atm. I read about EDID, but I'm not sure how to tackle this since it's getting really complicated

Comment: @yagmoth555 and the RDP-client is on the client computer. since it takes the monitor settings of the server, it thinks it only has one monitor connected, but it has 3 monitors.

Comment: The rdp client take the resolution of the endpoint, aka, if you are in 1204x768 and connect fullscreen the remote reoslution will be 1024x768.